# Boost prim_minimum_spanning_tree from a particular start vertex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

With a simple graph, it is straight forward to call prim_minimum_spanning_tree to get the result starting at vertex 0:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;

int main(int,char*[])
{
    // Create a graph object
    Graph g(3);

    EdgeWeightProperty e1 = 5;
    add_edge(0, 1, e1, g);

    EdgeWeightProperty e2 = 3;
    add_edge(1, 2, e2, g);

    std::vector < boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor > parents(num_vertices(g));

    prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, &parents[0]);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != parents.size(); ++i) {

      if (parents[i] != i) {
        std::cout << "parent[" << i << "] = " << parents[i] << std::endl;
      }
      else {
        std::cout << "parent[" << i << "] = no parent" << std::endl;
      }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

But I can't seem to decrypt the signature for specifying a different start vertex? It looks like this one is the only one that takes a `vertex_descriptor` (which I'm assuming is the start vertex?):

```
  prim_minimum_spanning_tree
    (const VertexListGraph& g,
     typename graph_traits<VertexListGraph>::vertex_descriptor s, 
     PredecessorMap predecessor, DistanceMap distance, WeightMap weight, 
     IndexMap index_map,
     DijkstraVisitor vis)
```

any suggestions on how to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires the "named parameter" signature:

```
prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, &parents[0], boost::root_vertex(1));
```

You can find the available named parameters under "Named Parameters" on the documentation page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.html